# Javascript scope issue with opensocial payment API

Tags: javascript, function, scope, social-networking, opensocial

I have a strange issue and I have been stuck for hours now. I am working on porting somebody's game to a social platform called Mixi. Now, there is a button inside the game which triggers a Javascript function with four parameters. (the game passes the values for these while calling.)

Now, I have written definition for this function calling the Mixi API for payment and if I call this function from anywhere within my file, the window/widget shows up. But, when it gets called from within the game, something messes up and it just crashes.

I have checked Console and it seems that something is wrong with the context or scope. If I put an alert in the same function, it gets called perfectly fine from within the game. But, since it is an API call and depends on objects from other JS files, included before this file in the Mixi application, I think opensocial.requestPayment malfunctions since context changes when function is called from within the game.

Same thing is observed for functionality like Inviting friends. A call from within the .js or another .js in the same application works fine but from within the game API call does not work, and the Network monitor in Firebug shows "rpc.json" something as the last thing. The same thing also comes when the function is called manually, but is immediately followed by something win_create.pl from the server of Mixi and shows up the dialog.

Code for the functions seems to be fine, since it works perfectly when called from this container web application. But from within the game, only the alerts come (means function is called) but API is not called correctly.

I have tried doing this:

```
var that = this; // outside the function
function sendPaymentRequest(itemName, amount etc.){
  that.opensocial.sendPaymentRequest... // works only if called from within this application
}
```

But this makes no difference, either.

I am sorry if this sounds confusing, as I didn't know how to explain this in a nutshell. If you need any further information, please let me know.

**Update:** Code Snippets:
The following function is used for calling opensocial's payment request:

```
function sendPaymentRequest(id, price, count, name, imageUrl) {

    var itemId = id;    
    var amount = price * count;
    var itemName = name;
    $.post(
        "http://url.com/payment.php",
        {"item_id":itemId, "item_price":amount, "item_name":itemName },
        function(data){

          var responseJSON = JSON.parse(data);
          //alert("Signature Fetched: "+ responseJSON.signature); -- this works 

          var params = {};
          params[opensocial.Payment.Field.AMOUNT]   = amount;
          params[mixi.Payment.Field.ITEM_NAME]      = "diamond";
          params[mixi.Payment.Field.SIGNATURE]      = responseJSON.signature;
          params[mixi.Payment.Field.ITEM_ID]        = id;
          params[mixi.Payment.Field.IS_TEST]        = 'true';
          params[mixi.Payment.Field.INVENTORY_CODE] = 123;
          params[opensocial.Payment.Field.PAYMENT_TYPE] = opensocial.Payment.PaymentType.PAYMENT;


          var payment = opensocial.newPayment(params);

          //alert("Just before opensocial request payment" + opensocial.requestPayment); -- works even when called from game    
          console.log(payment);
          opensocial.requestPayment(
                payment,
                "http://url.com/payment-callback.php",
                function(response){
                  var data;
                  var code;
                  var msg;

                  if (response.hadError()){
                    code = response.getErrorCode();
                    msg = response.getErrorMessage();
                    alert('code=' + code + ' msg=' + msg);
                  }else{
                    data = response.getData();
                    // alert('ok. itemNmae=' + data.fields_.itemName);
                  }
                }
           );




        });
}
```

This specific function is being called from within the game. But, the window for payment which this method is supposed to open doesn't show. However, if the same call to opensocial.requestPayment is made from anywhere within the javascript file from a global scope, it shows instantly.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, and maybe a link to a demo ?

Comment: There is no error message as such. When the function is called from within the game, Javascript crashes, the network monitor shows rpc.json with 200 OK but apparently, the call is not correct to the API because when the same function is called from within the application, that rpc.json does not crash and immediately a create.pl is triggered on Mixi's server. Since the application is not released yet, am afraid there is no way to show the demo. But, if you would like to see any specific code snippets, I would be glad to share. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Wow, i just noticed that Mixi is japanese… making impossible to find docs from my side. Anyway, can you show us how you initialize opensocial object ?

Comment: There are two files: index.php and game.js
game.js is included in index.php plus connect.js from Mixi whose URL is: https://static.mixi.jp/js/application/connect.js

These files are in this order: connect.js,and then game.js

I am adding the relevant snippets to the question above. Again, thanks !

Comment: Well, i'm afraid to be totally helpless with your problem :/ It's hard to guess what could be the problem while not being in front of a live demo. Just a few more question : where does the game run in ? Inside another JS app ? what is the DOM context ? An iFrame ?

Comment: The game runs in a PHP application which is used for OAuth part and payment handler, etc. This application links to the main Javascript that fetches the game file (.unity3d) from the game server. The function is being called from inside this game file.
DOM context is not clear to me when it is called from within the game. But when it is called from the context of the js file, it works fine... And yes, overall game runs inside an iFrame.

Comment: Check if iFrame doesn't have any sandbox properties (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp). Moreover, ajax requests are sent to Mixi platform and maybe you're facing a CORS problem. Do you have to set up an app in Mixi ? Is there any settings related to domains ?

Comment: Thanks for your constant help. But, am afraid there is no CORS issue. Just something to do with the call of sendPaymentRequest (as shown above) from within the game. Probably, some context issue. The function indeed gets triggered (checked with alerts) but opensocial.requestPayment does not work. The same function when called from this javascript file, it works !

Comment: OK, i don't think i'll be more helpfull :) But maybe Mixi has a support forum or something this way ? (if you speak japanese…)

Comment: Yeah... we speak Japanese, but sadly, they have no forum or community of developers... :(
Anyways, thanks for your time !

Comment: They have this platform http://developer.mixi.co.jp/ (but even with google trad i can't understand a lot :D )